# My flutter files showing error even though there is no red mark in code

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling

I have made 2 pages using flutter for my application.The files names are HomeBanner and home_screen. I don't know what is causing error in my files.
This is HomeBanner file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_portfolio/constants.dart';

class HomeBanner extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeBanner({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 3,
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            "/home/isha/Desktop/flutter_app/my_portfolio/assets/background.jpg",
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Container(
            color: darkColor.withOpacity(0.66),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: defaultPadding),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Discover about my space!",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3!.copyWith(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                ),
                MyApps(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my home_screen file that i made and i do not think i missed any dependency:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_portfolio/screens/home/HomeBanner.dart';
//import 'package:my_portfolio/constants.dart';
import 'package:my_portfolio/screens/main_screen.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MainScreen(
      children: [
        const HomeBanner(),
        Text(
          "My Projects",
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,
        ),
        // GridView.builder(
        //     shrinkWrap: true,
        //     itemCount: 9,
        //     gridDelegate:
        //         SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
        //     itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
        //           color: Colors.blueGrey,
        //         )),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the error:

```
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...              
lib/screens/home/home_screen.dart:13:15: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'HomeBanner'.
        const HomeBanner(),
              ^^^^^^^^^^
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...             42.1s
Failed to compile application.
```

Can anyone help with this..
Thank you!!

Comment: Hey I cant reproduce this error may be you have imported wrong file or something please check or close the debuging session & restart it it may work

Answer (score 0):

On the homebanner file you created a stateless widget and named it HomeBanner but the widgets name its looks like you forgot the change widget's name. Because currently the class name you are using is AdressInfo, change that class name with HomeBanner which you are calling from your home screen.

From;

```
class AddressInfo extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddressInfo({
    Key? key,
    this.title,
    this.text,
  });
```

To;

```
class HomeBanner extends StatelessWidget {
      const AddressInfo({
        Key? key,
        this.title,
        this.text,
      });
```

Comment: can you please check again. I just wrote different file under HomeBanner. This one is surely correct file. Sorry for mistake.

Comment: Please check the mainscreen extension you are currently using as a parent widget at HomeBanner() side, if MainScreen extension doesn't have a widget constructor such as Scaffold etc. it may cause this problem because that means also you don't have a body on your app.
If that extension don't have a constructor, you can simply wrap and add a Scaffold constructor then use that widget as a body. And make sure that your MainScreen widget returns on children.